# I want to print a random string on my current page

Tags: javascript

I'm new at javascript, but I want a random string. this string should be printed on my current page.
I already have:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
var strings = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);
var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
document.getElementById('randomString').innerHTML = randomString;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="randomString"></div>
</body>
```

according to JSFiddle, this should work, but it doesn't. what should I change?

Comment: Did you try to place the script at the bottom of the page? The div may not have been loaded yet.

Comment: hi, if you are new to javascript and web designing and programming, I suggest you to learn jquery or other javascript libraries. it will change you to a professional programmer, or make your own library that this way is really hard.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because your javascript is executed before the #randomString div exists. So, you need to either move your javascript after the #randomString div in the code, or use onLoad attribute of the  to execute the function when the document is ready, which means that you would need to wrap your current code in a function.

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the `div` with the id `randomString` before it exists in the DOM. Move the `<script>` to the bottom (somewhere after the `div`) and it'll work.

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="randomString"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
var strings = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 'ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);
var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
document.getElementById('randomString').innerHTML = randomString;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

btw, your code missed the `</html>`

Answer (score 1):

**You may try this :**

```
window.onload=function(){

var strings = ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',    'ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc'];
var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * strings.length);
var randomString = strings[randomIndex];
document.getElementById('randomString').innerHTML = randomString;

 }
```

Comment: hi: I think this is the best Answer.